# Why does pyodbc attempt to connect with a blank login when Integrated Security=True?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a Python script that tries to connect to a local database but fails.

```py
import pyodbc

connection_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=.;Database=testdb;Integrated Security=True;'
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")

According to the error, pyodbc tried to connect as '' (a blank). I ran the script as my Windows user, verified by running the command `whoami` in the same terminal from which I executed the script. I Googled `pyodbc "login failed for user ''"` but Google returned only results where the username in the error is not blank.

I can successfully connect via SQL Server Management Studio with Windows Authentication.

[image: connecting via SSMS]

[image: connected via SSMS, can see object explorer]

The error message also mentions an invalid connection string attribute. I checked https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ and I don't see the problem. Breaking it down we have:

Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};
Server=.;
Database=testdb;
Integrated Security=True;

All of these look correct to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I replaced `Integrated Security=True` with `Trusted_Connection=Yes` and it worked. I would post this as an answer, but I have no idea why `Integrated Security=True` was incorrect when https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ seems to indicate that either one should work.

Comment: connectionstrings.com is not a reliable source. If you check the official documentation at [ODBC] [DSN and Connection String Keywords and Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute) you'll notice that `Integrated Security` is not a listed connection property.

Comment: `Integrated Security=true` is valid for some connection methods (like "Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider for SQL Server"), but not for "SQL Server ODBC Driver …"